# Python / Cython optimization (3D kernel filter)

Tags: image-processing, optimization, cython

I'm tryin to optimize this loop in python:

```
def apply_kernel(X,Z,kernel):
    d=kernel.shape
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        for j in range(X.shape[1]):
            for k in range(X.shape[2]):

                X[i,j,k]=np.sum(kernel*Z[i:(i+d[0]),j:(j+d[1]),k:(k+d[2])])
    return X
```

I tried with cython:

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


ctypedef np.float64_t cpl_t
cpl = np.float64


@cython.boundscheck(False) # compiler directive
@cython.wraparound(False) # compiler directive
def appKernel( np.ndarray[ cpl_t, ndim=3] X,np.ndarray[ cpl_t, ndim=3] Z,np.ndarray[ cpl_t, ndim=3] kernel):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j, k, ik, jk, kk
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        for j in range(X.shape[1]):
            for k in range(X.shape[2]):

                for ik in range(kernel.shape[0]):
                    for jk in range(kernel.shape[1]):
                        for kk in range(kernel.shape[2]):
                            X[i,j,k]=X[i,j,k]+Z[i+ik,j+jk,k+kk]*kernel[ik,jk,kk]


    return X
```

There is an improvement (about 10 times faster); but I think that it could be better. Do you have any ideas on how to improve this?

Next step would be paralelize this using mpi4py.

Comment: try list comprehensions, which is a little bit faster than for loop block (in Python not Cython), and actually, do u really care about the 10ms speed in your code dude?

Comment: Yes, is not 10 ms. It can take hours. The size of the arrays X and Z are about 1024x1024x1024 or larger if possible, and the kernel may be 100x100x100. This is the core of code.

Comment: That looks like you've applied all the obvious optimizations to Cython (short of `prange`). Is this something where the real answer is to change the algorithm to use FFTs?

Comment: The idea is to stay at the real domain to use simple MPI parallelization. If I use a direct C/C++ code, could this be (much) faster?

Comment: Using a *better algorithm* like the FFT-based one proposed by DavidW is the best solution here, and actually by a huge margin (at least 1 order of magnitude, probably 2 or 3 with a good FFT library like the FFTW). Switching to C++ will not make the code drastically faster. Thus you need to rethink deeply the algorithm first. Then, and only then, you can make it run efficiently on your hardware using *multithreading* and possibly distributed computing.

Comment: Thanks very much both for your answer. Can you share some link with more info about this algorithm?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve

Comment: Agreed that you should look at another approach. If you want to gain more speed, you can declare the type of your loop variables, `i, j, k` etc. You could also save the dimension of your arrays, cache it in some variable.